# How do I open individual ports on the OSX Server Firewall?

Tags: mac-osx, firewall

In OSX server, the firewall is usually opened per Applicaation, not per port. However, I have a ton of self-compiled servers, and I find it more convenient to open their ports,  rather than select their binaries from somewhere. (It's often cumbersome to spot the "binary" in a server, between millions of scripts and binaries.)

How do I open individual ports on the OSX Server Firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of OS X Server?  Lion?

Are you sure it's "Server" & not just an OS X client you're using as a server?

If it is indeed OS X Server, make sure you're using Server Admin to manage the Firewall, not System Preferences -> Security & Privacy.  The latter controls the OS X Application Firewall, which it sounds like you were using.  The former controls the lower level BSD PF firewall, which is much better & actually acclaimed by most as the best firewall out there.  You can also use pfctl from the command line to manage the PF firewall if you want.

**Edit**

Sorry, some of that info above is wrong.  Apparently Server Admin still only manages ipfw, which is an older BSD firewall.  Still good, but not as good as PF.